# Problem loading panorama in SharePoint - redirect for image files

Tags: javascript, redirect, image

We have a panorama made with [krpano](http://krpano.com) that we would like to show in our SharePoint site. All the files and images have been uploaded, but when trying to run the panorama we get loading errors for the image files it is trying to load.

Upon checking the actual requests, the images are coming back with a status code of 302 (temporary redirect) and with an url of http://[mysite]/_layouts/15/Authenticate.aspx?Source=%2FSiteAssets%2FPanoramor%2FTAKTISKT%5FPANOdata%2Fgraphics%2Fclassiccontrolbar%2Fbtn%5Fmove%5Fdown%2Epng instead of just the url to the file which the panorama script is expecting.

Is there a way to set up the storage of the images on the SharePoint server so that it does not need to do the redirect to get the files? I've tried putting them in an image library and under Site Assets but it does not make any difference.

The server is SharePoint 2013, Foundation.

Comment: Your server most likely runs on HTTPS and it looks like you are trying to retrieve an image with HTTP. Try the original URL in the browser

Comment: @DannyEngelman The urls are relative when they're read, I've also tried adding the image manually using both html tags and javascript which works without a problem. But I'm guessing those two approaches can handle the redirect which the panorama script cannot.

Comment: @DannyEngelman The original url works fine in the browser.

Comment: @DannyEngelman I also don't see any use of HTTPS in any of the urls on the site.

Comment: Is this KRPano viewer doing something dirty and sending the request to their server, so that the image is loaded with a call from their server? (thus explaining the Authentication redirect) Check the network tab in F12 if any calls to outside locations are made when the page loads.

Comment: @DannyEngelman Nope, I don't see any requests to any other sites than our own SharePoint.

Comment: We're on a wild goose chase here without access... Next thing I can think of is this KRPano thingie requests images with a different/incorrect MimeType. Problem is with this KRpano code; if images load in SharePoint the problem is not with SharePoint.

Comment: How are running panorama in SharePoint? I mean what type of application is it? client side or server side? Does it run using a specific account?

Comment: @HarryB It is just images and javascript code, so client side.

Comment: @DannyEngelman Yeah, I'm sorry I can't give access. The krpano code is obfuscated to the moon and back so I can't see how it requests the images. I'll post in their forum as well and see if I can get some help that way but I'm expecting them to blame SharePoint.

Comment: Issue here is about authentication as the request for the image is being sent to the authentication page. Check in ULS logs what is happening before the redirect.

Comment: @HarryB ULS logs? Where can I find those? Another problem is that I don't actually administer the server, just the content.

Comment: ULS logs are stored on the SharePoint server. Best thing to do is to work with your SharePoint admin and monitor the logs as the request for the image is being made by the panorama. This will give you enough clues about why the request for images is going to the  authentication page.

Comment: You can also use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to monitor what requests are made.. be aware .. this tool is not for the fainthearted... BUT.. if the source code is obfuscated and not under your control just detecting what the problem is no solution. You might want to reconsider if you want to continue with this... Again.. SharePoint is not the problem.

Comment: @HarryB Thanks for trying to help, will take a look and see if I can talk to them.

Comment: @DannyEngelman Thanks for your suggestions. The problem at least arises *in combination* with SharePoint, as the panorama works perfectly on a regular web server. Knowing the exact problem would also help when asking their support (who probably know nothing of SharePoint) for help.